# PYODBC | Pandas : Write pandas dataframe from a nested JSON column SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, pyodbc

I spent over two days trying to solve this but still blocked.

I work with pyodbc and pandas in order to write a specific data ( `ID` and `Role` ) from a column called `ExtraData` ( a nested JSON ) into a pandas DataFrame.
The JSON in ExtraData is the following :

```
{"Data":{"Person":[{"Source":"C","ID":"45","Role":43}],"NoID":2}}
```

Here is my attempts :

```
import pyodbc
import json
import pandas.io.json as pd_json

#// Skip setting the connection string

crsr = conn.cursor()
query_json ="SELECT ExtraData FROM data"
test_data= crsr.execute(query_json).fetchall()
for row in test_data:
     test = json.dumps([x for x in row])
     data = pd_json.loads(test)
     print(data) #['{"Data":{"Person":[{"Source":"C","ID":"45","Role":43}],"NoID":2}}']
     df = pd_json.json_normalize(data, 
                                 record_path='Person', 
                                 meta=['ID', 'Role'])
     print(df)
```

I have the following error :

```
---> df = pd_json.json_normalize(data, record_path='Person', meta=['ID', 'Role'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Do you have an explanation pls? And how to avoid having this error ?

Comment: could be a simpler issue not related to json or queries, either you are trying to slice data from list using a wrong format ( x = mylist["index"]) or you are trying to get mylist[1,2], instead of  mylist[1:2]

Comment: What ODBC driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you help!
you should change code from:

```
import pyodbc
import json
import pandas.io.json as pd_json

crsr = conn.cursor()
query_json ="SELECT ExtraData FROM data"
test_data= crsr.execute(query_json).fetchall()
for row in test_data:
     test = json.dumps([x for x in row])
 data = pd_json.loads(test)
 print(data)
 df = pd_json.json_normalize(data, 
                             record_path='Person', 
                             meta=['ID', 'Role'])
 print(df)
```

to

```
import pyodbc
import json
import pandas.io.json as pd_json

crsr = conn.cursor()
query_json ="SELECT ExtraData FROM data"
test_data= crsr.execute(query_json).fetchall()
for row in test_data:
     test = json.dumps([x for x in row])
 data = pd_json.loads(test[0]) ** this line!
 print(data)
 df = pd_json.json_normalize(data, 
                             record_path='Person', 
                             meta=['ID', 'Role'])
 print(df)
```

Comment: This is still not working, having the same error message :(